# Problem with fetching records from database with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need little help with the three functions below. I expect the functions to take the records daily, monthly and all records of the current year. However, I notice on the daily report the amount of 'scrap' is around 126 meanwhile monthly and year reports are showing 32.

Why 126 'scrap' in the daily report is not included in the others reports? Thank you in advance.

```
public async Task<List<Scrap>> GetDailyScrap()
{
    return await _dbContext.Scrap.Where(x => 
                    x.Created.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && 
                    x.Created.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && 
                    x.Created.Day == DateTime.Now.Day).ToListAsync();
}
public async Task<List<Scrap>> GetMonthlyScrap()
{
    return await _dbContext.Scrap.Where(x => 
                    x.Created.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && 
                    x.Created.Month == DateTime.Now.Month).ToListAsync();
}
public async Task<List<Scrap>> GetYearScrap()
{
    return await _dbContext.Scrap.Where(x => 
                    x.Created.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).ToListAsync();
}
```

[image: charts]

The amount of scrap for KST-420(daily chart) to reflect with the correct numbers on the monthly and year report.

- Scrap Model :

```cs
public class Scrap
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ScrapLineId { get; set; }

    public string Line { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Position { get; set; }

    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public int Shift { get; set; }

    public int ShiftLeaderPersonalId { get; set; }

    public int OperatorPersonalId { get; set; }
    
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public int Week { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

}
```

endpoint:

```cs
    //Daily Bar Chart SCRAP
    List<Scrap> dailyScrap = await _scrapService.GetDailyScrap();
    List<string> xValues = dailyScrap.DistinctBy(x => x.Line).Select(x => x.Line).ToList();
    List<int> yValues = dailyScrap.DistinctBy(x => x.Quantity).Select(x => x.Quantity).ToList();

    // Monthly Bar Chart SCRAP
    List<Scrap> monthlyScrap = await _scrapService.GetMonthlyScrap();
    List<string> xValuesMonthly = monthlyScrap.DistinctBy(x => x.Line).Select(x => x.Line).ToList();
    List<int> yValuesMonthly = monthlyScrap.DistinctBy(x => x.Quantity).Select(x => x.Quantity).ToList();

    // Year Bar Chart SCRAP
    List<Scrap> yearScrap = await _scrapService.GetYearScrap();
    List<string> xValuesYear = yearScrap.DistinctBy(x => x.Line).Select(x => x.Line).ToList();
    List<int> yValuesYear= yearScrap.DistinctBy(x => x.Quantity).Select(x => x.Quantity).ToList();
```

[charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHHfK.png)

Comment: Please share more details about your underlying model and EF configuration.

Comment: Does it make a difference if, for testing purposes, you replace the `DateTime.Now.*` values with hardcoded numbers? I'm asking this because EF will in some cases attempt to interpret your code directly instead of using the underlying value. Another test you can do, is create a variable for those values, and use the variables in the query. See if that makes a difference in the results.

Comment: And lastly, do the SQL queries generated by EF make sense to you? You can check the queries in the console or by checking the `IQueryable` in the debugger.

Comment: Those queries result in conditions like `YEAR(created)=2023 AND MONTH(created)....` that can't use any indexes. Use a range condition instead, eg `.Where(x => x.Created>=DateTime.Today && x.Created <DateTime.Today.AddDays(1))`. The resulting query will use a simple range condition, eg `created >='2023-01-17 AND created < '2024-01-18'`

Comment: Maybe it is you grouping that is wrong, which does not seems to be in the code posted.

Comment: Additionally, those charts *don't* show an unconditional count for a single day, they show what looks the result of a `GroupBy`. What's the *actual* query? How were those values generated?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I assume that might be the problem, I tried to provide more code that is related to the problem.

Comment: I understand the `DistinctBy` on the x-values; however, I cannot get around the `DistinctBy` for the y-values. For a bar chart you need the maximum value to get the range of the y-axis and a sum (probably done by the chart). If it's not done by the chart, you would group by the x-values and take the sum in each group for the bar heights.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I realized that problem a few minutes ago. When the amount of xValues  and yValues is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way these queries are written, they count individual values, not the count or sum of items per line. For example, `101` and `102` would produce an Y value of 2, while 100 individual `100`s would produce 1.

To get totals by line, use `GroupBy` and `Count` or `Sum`, eg :

```
var dailies=dailyScrap.GroupBy(s=>s.Line)
                      .Select(g=>new 
                          { 
                              X=g.Key, 
                              Y=g.Sum(s=>s.Quantity)
                          })
                      .ToList();
```

This can be done in EF Core too, retrieving only the totals from the database :

```
var dateFrom=DateTime.Today;
var dateTo=dateFrom.AddDays(1);

var dailies=_dbContext.Scrap
                      .Where(s=> s.Created>=dateFrom 
                              && s.Created <dateTo)
                      .GroupBy(s=>s.Line)
                      .Select(g=>new 
                          { 
                              X=g.Key, 
                              Y=g.Sum(s=>s.Quantity)
                          })
                      .ToList()
```

This generates

```
SELECT Line,SUM(Quantity)
FROM Scrap
WHERE Created >=@d1 && Created < @d2
GROUP BY Line
```

The condition can be simplified to only `Where(s=> s.Created>=DateTime.Today)` if there are no future values.

The query can be adapted to cover any period by changing the `From` and `To` parameters, eg :

```
var dateFrom=new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year,DateTime.Today.Month,1);
var dateTo=dateFrom.AddMonths(1);
```

or

```
var dateFrom=new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year,1,1);
var dateTo=dateFrom.AddYears(1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I will need to take some tutorial regarding 'GroupBy' to avoid mistakes.